# Catch browser starting in a Service Android

Tags: android, service, hyperlink, browser

Is it possible to catch when the link was clicked in Android Service.
I do know that it is impossible to catch onTouch Event in the service. But maybe WebBrowser starting is possible?. Please help! Very Important.
I need to start my Web Based app when the specific link was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An activity can be registered to be started using a url, which you define in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="yourscheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Your activity will then be launched if a link looking like `yourscheme://something` is clicked

Comment: one more question - can I put my host value in <data> tag somehow programaticaly ?